# Extending the django admin log causing unknown column in where clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I've got a requirement to store an audit log of various actions on a django site so I've extended the standard log model to accommodate the extra information we need to store.

models.py;

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from consoles.models import Client, Console

class AuditLogEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def log_action(self, user_id, content_type_id, object_id, object_repr,
                   action_flag, change_message='', client=None, console=None):
        e = self.model(
            None, None, user_id, content_type_id, smart_text(object_id),
            object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message, client, console
        )
        e.save()


class AuditLog(LogEntry):
    """
    Providing additional properties to the django admin log.
    """

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    console = models.ForeignKey(Console, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    objects = AuditLogEntryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('log entry')
        verbose_name_plural = _('log entries')
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'
        ordering = ('-action_time',)
```

And I've setup a class to log actions;

```
class Audit(object):
    ADDITION = ADDITION
    CHANGE = CHANGE
    DELETION = DELETION

    def ct(self, object):
        return ContentType.cache.get(object)

    def logged_in(self, user, console=None, client=None, message=None):
        if not message:
            message = _("{} logged in".format(user.username))
        object_repr = u'(%s) %s' % (user.id, user.username)

        AuditLog.objects.log_action(
            user_id=user.id,
            content_type_id=self.ct(user).pk,
            object_id=user.pk,
            object_repr=object_repr,
            action_flag=ADDITION,
            change_message=message, client=client, console=console
        )
```

When I try to call `logged_in(request.user)` after a user successfully logs in, I get a SQL error `OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'django_admin_log.logentry_ptr_id' in 'where clause'")`

I assume this is in relation to my extension of the `django_admin_log` table but I'm not so good with SQL. Could someone explain the issue, and perhaps provide a better solution?